# download_to_filename makes an empty file (google cloud storage)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Answer:
I needed to grant ownership access to the storage policy and not just grant a general API ownership to the IAM connected to my instance.

I have simply followed the tutorial on the website here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python

Which says

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name))

download_blob([BUCKETNAME],[FILENAME],"/home/me/documents/file.png")
```

I don't receive an error but the last line to be executed is blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

Which creates an empty file.

Additional info:
My bucket is in the format "mybucketname"
my file is in the format "sdg-1234-fggr-34234.png"

I hope anyone has knowledge about my issue.
Is it encoding? Or doesn't the download_to_filename execute? Or something else?

Comment: I think it might be my "source_blob_name", but I'm just using the name as it is in the bucket. This is so frustrating..

Comment: I tried that code to download a file from a bucket and it worked. In your case it should be downloading the file "sdg-1234-fggr-34234.png" from your bucket "mybucketname"  to the “"/home/me/documents/” directory with the name “file.png”. Is it creating a empty file “file.png” on the directory that you mentioned?

Comment: Thank you for testing my code. Yeah it creates an empty file in my directory. I think it might be authorization failure on my part, but I don't get any errors. I think I'm going to explore that.

Comment: Can I ask you how you handle auth? I'm using a compute engine to run the code above. The instance uses a default service account with full access to all apis. I access the instance through the console ssh.

To my knowledge it's supposed to be straight forward.
I'm just importing:
 from google.cloud import storage

Nothing else. Do I need to do auth in the beginning of my code?

Comment: Hmm I can list all objects in the bucket and I can list all my buckets, but I can't download any files for some reason...

Comment: I also used the default service account. I started by following this tutorial[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart] and then I added the code you are using to test it, didn't need to add the auth.

Comment: This is weird. Okay, in my setup i'm not using a local webserver. I'm just doing it in compute engine.

I have started looking at error reports around download_to_filename() at places like this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3747

I have no idea what I'm doing..

Comment: I finally solved the problem.. I had set the IAM account to owner on a general level, but not in the specific storage menu. This solved it and it downloads the file now. Thanks for helping with troubleshooting.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works now. @Christian may I ask you to post the solution as an answer?

Comment: Of course. I have added it in my initial question.

Comment: Please remove "solved" from your title and move your solution to its own answer. Thank you.

Comment: How did you change the IAM account to owner for the storage menu?

Answer (score 1):

When working with API's it's important to grant ownership access to the storage policy and not just grant a general API ownership to the IAM connected to an instance.